# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
     <property name="username" value="system"/>
     <property name="password" value="manager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="datasource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectdao" class="com.query.dao.ProjectDAO">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"/> 
</bean>
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'projectdao' defined in class path resource [com/query/comman/application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'projectdao' defined in class path resource [com/query/comman/application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:670)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:191)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>               at com.query.test.projectTest.main(projectTest.java:11)

Answer (score 0):

Problem would be, You have not written the constructor which accepts JDBCTemplate as a parameter in your `com.query.dao.ProjectDAO` class

```
public class ProjectDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

    public ProjectDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate; 
    }
}
```